# Simple Python xml image generator

Tags: python, xml, windows

I need a simple python script to look in a folder get the image filenames which there 100 in each folder and output and xml as such:

```
    <image src = "img_3.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_4.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_5.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_6.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_7.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_8.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_9.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_10.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_11.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_12.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_13.jpg"/>
    <image src = "img_14.jpg"/>
```

where the `img_X.jpg` is the image name from inside the folder. my images are named `851_r016_OUTPUT_JPG_001`, `851_r016_OUTPUT_JPG_002` and so forth. I know its possible just don't know how to make it happen.

Just to clarify I need help with a python script that will search in a specified windows folder grab all the image names in that folder and output an xml with the above format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PyXB](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net) and define an 'MyImages' XSD Object, and it will auto generate the code for you - the class and it's methods, including "append", "read"(xml file) and "toxml"(write).

XSD schema:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:complexType name="MyImages">
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:complexType name="image">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="src"   type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The next step will be simple code, for example:

```
from os import listdir
from MyImages import MyImages # auto-generated .py file

myimages = MyImages()
for imagePath in listdir('dirPath'):
    im = MyImages.image()
    im.src = imagePath
    myimages.append(im)

with open("output.xml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(myimages.toxml("utf-8"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this as a starting point:

```
import os
for i in os.listdir('your/directory/'):
    print(i)
```